# CKEditor with JQuery UI Dialog - does not show up second time

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to implement the CKEditor inside an JQuery UI Dialog, when the dialog opens first time it works perfect.

When I open the dialog the second time, the text area as as "style:hidden" and editor is not loaded?

Dialog

```
MyApp.Dialog = $('<div></div>');
        MyApp.Dialog
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: title,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            close:function(){
                $(this).find('textarea').ckeditorGet().destroy();
            },
            buttons: {
                'OK': function() {
                    form = $(this).find('form');
                    if (form.validate().form() == true) {
                        MyApp.submitFormWithAjax(form, $(this));
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

        MyApp.Dialog.load(url, function() {
            EventManager.publish('showFormDialogLoaded');
        });

        MyApp.Dialog.dialog('open');
```

on my admin page I am waiting that the dialog is loaded..

```
$('.admin-create-article').click(function(event) {
       MyApp.showFormDialog($(this).attr('href'), 'Neuer Artikel', 700, 630);
       EventManager.subscribe('showFormDialogLoaded', function() {
             $('.editor').ckeditor( function() {}, { skin : 'v2' } );
       });
       event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, but now it works for me.

You must do that on each dialog construct (create and destroy the ckeditor):

```
if  (CKEDITOR.instances.editorD != null && CKEDITOR.instances.editorD != 'undefined')
     {
       CKEDITOR.instances.editorD.destroy();
     }

      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editorD',
      {
       language : 'fr',
       toolbar_Mytoolbardata :
       [
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'],
        ['FontName','FontSize'],
        ['TextColor']// No comma for the last row.
       ],
       toolbar : 'Mytoolbardata',
       skin: 'v2',
       width : 403,      
       height : 25,
       disableObjectResizing : true,
       resize_enabled : false,
       shiftEnterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
       toolbarCanCollapse : false,
       forcePasteAsPlainText : true 
      });
```

Comment: With ckeditor v4.3, I did not get the problem of having the problem of editor not launched the second time but I got the dropdown elements of the toolbar not working on the second time. This solution solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Script files are not loaded or conflict with some other scripts like jquery UI script.

Comment: everything works when i open the dialog first time, if i click the link again the dialog opens but editor is missing.